# Caching a semi-dynamic view in Django

Tags: django, caching, django-templates, django-views

I have a view in Django which is "semi-dynamic". In my case, it serves different content to first time visitors and returning visitors. I know that my view can run all sorts of logic before rendering the response, but that would make caching in the view (and beyond) level impossible, because different types of users (according to cookie, session data or user data) will get a different response.

I'm thinking of several options to implement this:

- Redirect from my view to another view which is cached. I don't like this approach because it affects the UX (changes the URL). I know that if I'd ever want to cache in the HTTP server level, I'll need to opt for that approach.
- Cache in the template level using the cache tag (can practically cache the entire template, head to toe). That way, I can still use different templates for each case. It's an OK approach, I guess, it still involves running the template engine which is something I'd rather avoid.
- Cache the ready HttpResponse objects myself in the view using the caching framework directly. Practically this sounds like it would offer the best performance, but it feels a bit like "reinventing the wheel".

Any other ideas?  Any standard way of doing that which I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the cache template tag is your best bet when dealing with dynamic responses. Any time you're varying on things like logged in users, session stores, etc, you're simply not going to be able to cache the whole response. Caching the non-changing bits of your template with the cache template tag is the next best thing. Then, at least, only the actual dynamic parts need to be processed.

Comment: Naturally, dynamic parts of the template cannot be cached. In my case, I only have 2 options to go with, so it's not entirely dynamic. I'd feel better if I could cache each of them completely, like a complete view cache.

Comment: You can use the cache API *inside* your view to cache querysets and such, and you can use the cache template tag to cache portions of your HTML, but when you cache the entire view (using one of the decorators), the response itself is cached, which includes the fully-formed HTML document. So, if any part of the page needs to change, view-caching is out (unless its depends on something you can vary on such as authentication).

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear. As an example, you can take the the dynamic content caching introduced by AWS CloudFront a couple of weeks ago. http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/05/amazon-cloudfront-support-for-dynamic-content.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. All AWS dynamic content caching allows is to use a query string to differentiate resources. Django already does that by default. It builds the cache key based on both the URL and query string, so if the query string is different, it won't use the cache. However, that hardly helps you because then it just puts you into the situation where you're constantly invalidating the cache, so you might as well not cache.

Comment: I was using AWS just as an example. If I could somehow add to that cache key, that would completely solve my problem. Perhaps adding a "get_cache_key" method to the view that gets all the view args and can be implemented if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can cache the page and vary the bits of the page that are dynamic. This can be achieved using [two-phased-rendering](https://github.com/codysoyland/django-phased).